# Can we benefit from DDOS package if we are already using express-rate-limit?

Tags: express, ddos, rate-limiting

I implemented the [Express-rate-limit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-rate-limit) npm module on my code (nodejs)
I saw the [DDOS Module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ddos).

Anyone who have good expertise on Nodejs please suggest me that wheher I have to use DDOS module or not.

I installed the module but this will block the request. I read about express rate-limit also, this module is also working same as DDOS.

Someone suggest me that use DDOS. I told that I already used Express-Rate-Limit but he said that Use this also.

I am confused now. Please give me the Proper input regarding this. Any help is really appreciate.

Comment: Fundamentally, you can’t defeat a proper DDoS with npm packages. The fact that the request reaches your server at all and needs to be processed by node in itself will overwhelm the server in a proper DDoS attack. Some low-level traffic increase is probably all that can be deflected by those packages.

Comment: @deceze First of all really thanks for your precious reply. Second is so whether I use that module or not. Because after that I have to mention White-list IP because it will block after 40 request. On documentation there is burst and limit that I can't understand.

Answer (score 1):

it's fine as basic shield from ddos, or handling external requests for your api methods, that can go-out-of limit.
But if you want to prevent real ddos attacks, your should check debouncing and event throttling. Also think about per-machine custom firewall configurations;)

Dig a bit more into docs of this module ;)

> burst Burst is the number or amount of allowable burst requests before
>   the client starts being penalized. When the client is penalized, the
>   expiration is increased by twice the previous expiration.

bursts = base request counter for 1 unit of time, defined by default as 1 second, or a custom set up

limit

> limit is the number of maximum counts allowed (do not confuse that
>   with maxcount). count increments with each request. If the count
>   exceeds the limit, then the request is denied. Recommended limit is to
>   use a multiple of the number of bursts.

requests received => check for the limit. If limit achieved, requester gets a penalty.
When you see a lot of requests(multiple bursts detected).
That's real detection for excide of request limit. 
So, 5 bursts set, 20 as limit, when burst detected as 5, it will flag 20 request counter like a fully recognized limitation

maxexpiry

> maxexpiry is the seconds of maximum amount of expiration time. In
>   order for the user to use whatever service you are providing again,
>   they have to wait through the expiration time.

And that's it. Just dive into testing this stuff;)

Comment: I set {burst: 20, limit: 80}, because on my frontend server there is few api calls automatically after 3 sec. Earlier it will block the request. Is this okay @andriiklubuk

Comment: that's ok ;) must be fine for all your needs